# Select usage for certificate in nokia 2690 , app signing option is disabled

Tags: java-me, certificate, nokia

I've installed own certificate for j2me app on nokia 2690, But the usage of the certificate cannot be set to 'App signing' the option is disabled. I've done the same in N72 model without any problem, Please tell me if there is any solution.